# Расшифровка криптограммы, Лисп

Tags: lisp

Вот код функций, которые у меня есть:

```
(setq list ' ((((Ш К Э Ы О) (( )) (Ы)) ((Ш Ы Ж ((( ))) Т Ы) (З М Т Э ( ) К) (Щ Й У O)) (( )) ((Д У З И Э) ( ((( ))) Ш С Э П П) (Ш) ( ) ) 
((Г Щ Щ У Т) ( ) )) (((Ъ З С П ( ) Ь) (Ь)) ((Л Р (( )) П )) ((С Щ Ь Х ( ) Р) (Ч Е Ш П Д) ( ) ) ((Ы И О Ф Е) ((( ))) (Ы К)) ((Ш М) ( ) ) 
((Ф Ш С Э Ъ) ( ) (Ф Э К))) ((( ((( ))) Х Л Ш О А) (Й) (( )) ) ((М Р О А Ш) ( ) (П Д)))))

(defun badp (Z)
     (cond 
           ((null Z) T)
           ((atom Z) nil)
           ((and (null (cdr Z))
                 (listp (car Z)))
            (badp (car Z)))
           ((atom (car Z)) nil)
           (t nil)
           ))

 (defun clear (Y)
     (cond
           ((null Y) nil)
           ((badp (car Y)) (clear (cdr Y)))
           ((listp (car Y)) (cons (clear (car Y)) (clear (cdr Y))))
           (t (cons (car Y) (clear (cdr Y))))
           ))

 (clear list)

(defun OneList (X)
      (cond
                  ((null X) nil)
                  ((listp (car X)) (append (oneList (car X)) (OneList (cdr X))))
                  (T (cons (car X) (OneList (cdr X))))
                  ))

(onelist list)

(defun alfavit (d)
     (let ((result nil))
        (loop for l from 0 to 31
          do (setq result (cons (list-to-delimited-string
                                 (list (+ l (- d 1)) - (int-char (+ 192 
                                                                    l))) " ")
                            result))
          ) (list-to-delimited-string (reverse result) ", ") ))

(alfavit 1)

(defun preGamm (text key ngamma)
     (LET* ( (spisok (coerce text 'list))
       (keyspisok (coerce text 'list))
            (j 0) (n (- (length keyspisok) 1)) (result nil))
        (for i from 0 to (- (length spisok) 1) do
          (if (= ngamma 1)
             (PROGN
               (setq result (cons (nth j keyspisok) result))
               (if (< j n) (setq j (+ j 1)) (setq j 0))
               )
             (if (OR (equal (nth i spisok) #\space)
                     (equal (nth i spisok) #\.))
                (setq result (cons (nth i spisok) result))
                (PROGN 
                  (setq result (cons (nth j keyspisok) result))
                  (if (< j n) (setq j (+ j 1)) (setq j 0))
                  ))
             )) (list-to-delimited-string (reverse result) "")))

(defun Vigener-MG (text key ngamma)
    (LET ( (source (coerce text 'list))
          (keygamma (coerce (pregamm text key ngamma) 'list))
          (kriptogramma nil))
       (for i from 0 to (- (length source) 1) do
         (if (OR (equal (nth i source) #\space)
                 (equal (nth i source) #\.))
            (setq kriptogramma (cons (nth i source) kriptogramma))
            (setq kriptogramma (cons (int-char (+ 192
                                           (mod (- (+ 32
                                           (- (char-int (nth i source)) 192))
                                            (- (char-int (nth i keygamma)) 192))
                                                    32))) kriptogramma)))
         ) (list-to-delimited-string (reverse kriptogramma) "")))
```

Функции Vigener-MG и preGamm из методички, там же есть и функция частоты появления литер в криптограмме и все. Как я поняла Vigener-MG и preGamm - это для зашифровки текста, а мне надо расшифровать криптограмму, то есть наоборот.
Задание: Шифр Виженер-мг, ключ "ЗЕРКАЛ", номер гаммирования - 1(без разрыва на пробел и конец предложения, то есть ключ ЗЕРКАЛ повторять также там где есть точки и пробелы), Предикат ошибки: если-подсписок без элементов - это у меня делает функция Clear, которая удаляет эти "луковицы".
OneList функцию сказали написать для удаления всех внутренних скобок

Лисп у нас впервые поэтому не понимаю как переделать Vigener-MG и preGamm для расшифровки моей криптограммы

Comment: Не хочется разбираться в этой стене кода. Мне не ясно что это за алгоритм. Может вы сами разберётесь с ней, а когда возникнет более конкретная проблема, зададите вопрос?

Comment: в том то и дело, что не могу разобраться.

Comment: вот [здесь](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm) находится справочник функций Common Lisp, а [здесь](http://lisper.ru/pcl/) доступный учебник на русском по Common Lisp. Разбирайтесь.

Comment: Не знаю, наверное в Common Lisp (программа на нем ?) upper и lowcase не важны (т.е  T и t или OneList  и oneList) это одно и то же. В Emacs это не так. Попробовал Ваш код и наткнулся на это.

Исправлять лень ! У Вас то, **что конкретно** не идет ?

Comment: все идет, просто это алгоритмы для зашифровки, а зачем мне зашифровывать ещё раз криптограмму? мне нужны обратный алгоритм Vigener-MG
среда: ALLEGRO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Читайте описание алгоритма Виженера - http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0
2. Вам ничего с уже имеющимися функциями делать не надо. Нужно написать свои для расшийровки.
3. Очевидно, что алгоритм зашифровки не всегда эквивалентен алгоритму расшифровки. Порой их сложность может отличаться на порядки, а преобразования быть неочевидными. Поэтому читайте полное описпние алгоритма и реализовывайте его в виде кода.

Comment: вот пытаюсь разобраться и возник вопрос. вот моя криптограмма без "мусора":
((((Ш К Э Ы О) (Ы)) ((Ш Ы Ж Т Ы) (З М Т Э К) (Щ Й У Щ)) ((Д У З И Э) (Ш С Э П П) (Ш)) ((Г Щ Щ У Т))) (((Ъ З С П Ь) (Ь)) ((Л Р П)) ((С Щ Ь Х Р) (Ч Е Ш П Д)) ((Ы И О Ф Е) (Ы К)) ((Ш М)) ((Ф Ш С Э Ъ) (Ф Э К))) (((Х Л Ш О А) (Й)) ((М Р О А Ш) (П Д))))
там где внутри открываются по 2 скобочки - это слово, там где по три скобочки - предложение.
Как мне убрать эти скобки и между словами поставить пробел, а между предложениями точку с пробелом? Слова например: Ш К Э Ы О Ы_Ш Ы Ж Т Ы З М Т Э К Щ Й У Щ - это сенсор_ультразвуково

Comment: уже разобралась, вопрос снят

Comment: Объясните, как вы символ '-' в "сенсор-ультразвуковой" из этой криптограммы вытащили ???